# Custom new task form for list workflow

Tags: 2007

I fairly new to sharepoint.  I just started working with it for about a year now.  i have been teaching myself as i go. anyways, here my problem.  I have this task list.  im trying to edit the forms with this task list.  I don't need to edit the editform.aspx.  i need to edit the newform.aspx.  both forms are showing the same fields(columns/content types).  i want to remove some fields from the newform.  when my users go to create a new task, i only need them to fill out certian fields not all the fields.  is there a way to edit the newform.aspx or am i SOL.